# Laravel: How to access config/Mail variables

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get address and name variables on my Mail.php config:

```
'from' => ['address' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'name' => env('MAIL_NAME')],
```

I tried this:

```
Config::get('mail.from.*.name');
Config::get('mail.from["name"]');
```

But it doesn't work, what do I do to get them? Thanks.

Comment: Tried `Config::get('mail.from.name');` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can directly access MAIL_NAME from .env

```
env('MAIL_NAME');
```

**OR**

```
Config::get('mail.from.name');
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: Yeah that is it !

Comment: overall it's better to use the config method, in a production environment with the "config:cache" command advised in the doc the .env file isn't accessible

Answer (score 5):

this is the shortest method i know using helper methods :

```
config('mail.from.name')
```

or you can access it using your .env file with `env('MAIL_NAME')`

Answer (score 0):

it is preferable put your mail name in your configuration file and access it with env function like this :

```
env('MAIL_NAME')
```

Comment: Better to use the `config()` helper. Laravel will use what `config()` returns, so changing the config to `'from' => ['address' => 'hardcoded@example.com', 'name' => 'Something Hard Coded'],` would cause this to output the wrong information.